# delphi opensoure xml writer & reader

Tags: xml, delphi, open-source, delphi-2009

could you recommend a good XML open source writer and reader,

to generate and read XMLs?

Comment: Does it really need to be open source, or do you just want something that doesn't cost any money? Delphi already comes with royalty-free XML components.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[NativeXml](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html) and [OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com/) are open source and popular XML libraries for Delphi. [ADOM](http://www.philo.de/xml/downloads.shtml) is another, it is included in some versions of Delphi. For some advanced use cases, [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) with the Delphi wrapper [Libxml2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libxml2-pas/) might be interesting.

Comment: I use OmniXML lots, and I love it.   Pure open source, full source code. No third party or platform-specific requirements, which is the reason I stay away from MSXML wrappers.